# Electron: Can we access BrowserWindow using its unique id?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Assuming the below function is called multiple times to create BrowserWindow, say 5 times.

```
let mainWindow;

function createWindow() {
    "use strict";

    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ 
        height: height,
        width: width,
        minHeight: height,
        minWidth: width,
        icon: __dirname + iconPath,
        frame: false,
        backgroundColor: '#FFF',
        show: false
    });

    mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({ 
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, address),
        protocol: 'file',
        slashes: true
    }));

    mainWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
        mainWindow.show();
        mainWindow.focus();
    });

    mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
        mainWindow = null;
    });
}
```

this will generate 5 different BrowserWindow.

Does BrowserWindow has it's own unique id to identify? Or can we assign a unique id on it so that we can access them using its own id?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes it does. You can get it like this: `mainWindow.id` And it'll be something like `1` or `2` depending on how many windows were already open when this window opened.

Also you can get a `BrowserWindow` from it's id like this:

```
var myWindow = BrowserWindow.fromId(id);
```

[`BrowserWindow.fromId` Docs.](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#browserwindowfromidid)

[`window.id` Docs.](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winid)