# Electron - close renderer from main handler

Tags: javascript, electron

TLDR: Best way to close a renderer window from main (or the renderer itself).

I am splitting up a process between X invisible renderer windows. When a renderer finishes its work, I want it to send an event to the main process and then close. Right now I have

```
//invisibleRenderer.js
doStuff().then(() => {
  ipcRenderer.invoke('finish');
}
```

What is the best way to close the window? Is it in the ipcMain.handle? I can't figure out which method to call with which id.

```
ipcMain.handle('finish', (event, args) => {
  //do what? event.frameId, event.processId, event.sender.id...
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Electron: Can we access BrowserWindow using its unique id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53880880/electron-can-we-access-browserwindow-using-its-unique-id)

Comment: Not quite. The difference here is I am doing it inside the ipcMain so I don't know which id to use. There are 3 different ids in the event object (event.frameId, event.processId, event.sender.id). For now I am doing this but I do not know if it is the best:
`let win = BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().find(x=>x.webContents.id == event.sender.id);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`BrowserWindow.fromId`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#browserwindowfromidid)`(event.sender.id)` to get a reference to the window from where the IPC call originated, as demonstrated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53880880/electron-can-we-access-browserwindow-using-its-unique-id).

This works fine in the main process. The following example opens 5 windows and loads the same contents. Each renderer script invocation picks a random delay (to simulate some work) and then dispatches the `finish` message to the main process. There, the main process picks up the BrowserWindow reference using `event.sender.id` and closes the corresponding window.

**app.js**

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain} = require("electron");

const windows = [];

app.on("ready", function() {
    for (let i=0; i<5; i++) {
        let win;
        win = new BrowserWindow( {
            width: 300,
            height: 300,
            x: i*100,
            y: i*100,
            webPreferences: {
                nodeIntegration: true,
                contextIsolation: false
            },
        });

        win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`);
        windows.push(win);
    }
});

ipcMain.handle("finish", (event, args) => {
    const win = BrowserWindow.fromId(event.sender.id);
    win.close();
});
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<body>
Renderer
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="renderer.js"></script>
</html>
```

**renderer.js**

```
const {ipcRenderer} = require("electron");
// Simulate some work by choosing a random delay..
const delay = Math.round(Math.random()*10000);
setTimeout(() => ipcRenderer.invoke("finish"), delay);
```